# odd thing with php processing using POST

Tags: php, post

I have a project that works on a test server but stopped working when moved onto another.
Mainly I think it's the PHP but I ma here to ask your opinion.
So my main page is a HTML for login that has a form with POST that calls a php script file, like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="prologin.php">
    Name: <input type="text" name="nam"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pas"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" data-inline="true" data-icon="gear">
</form>
```

An the prologin.php file looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'mycon.php';
$nume1=mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['nam'] );
$pass1=mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['pas'] );

$s = "SELECT * FROM uzers WHERE uzname = '$nume1' and pass = md5('$pass1')";

var_dump($s);
... followed by other validations and stuff.
```

When I run the HTML file and click the Submit button (Login), I receive an "Undefined" page in Chrome or Firefox, and when I "view the source" I see the sql above with empty values. That is:

```
string(56) "SELECT * FROM uzers WHERE uzname = '' and pass = md5('')"
```

What could be wrong?
Why does php not receive the REQUEST variables? Because that is what I assume that happens.
What can I do to fix it?

Comment: the next step in a basic debugging attempt would be to inspect the values of your variables. `var_dump($_REQUEST); `var_dump($_POST);`. after that, remove the include and repeat.

Comment: Do you know what version of PHP is running on the server on which the code doesn't work? The `$_REQUEST` superglobal is only available from PHP version 4.1.0 onwards.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why aren't you using `$_POST` and using `$_REQUEST` instead?

Comment: Why do you start a session?

Comment: check your permissions onto the sessions folder

Comment: @vinodadhikary REQUEST is usefull if you are not decided how you want to send the parameters to the page (GET or POST). Supposedly REQUEST will contain either POST or GET values.

Comment: @meda I start a session because I use session variables all acrosss the app, and they tend to get lost if I do not start a session on each php file where I use the session variables.

Comment: @Sebas the sessions folder has 40766 chmod rights. I do not think that this is the problem. Especially since it does the same even if I remove the session_start line

Comment: @user1137313 what is your php version

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you first loading the page before submitting the form, at this case $_REQUEST or $_POST not exists, you can avoid this by checking the variables:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['nam']) && isset($_REQUEST['pas'])){
  include 'mycon.php';
  $nume1=mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['nam'] );
  $pass1=mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['pas'] );

  $s = "SELECT * FROM uzers WHERE uzname = '$nume1' and pass = md5('$pass1')";
  //other staff
}
```

Comment: I know. That is exactly my impression. However I don't know what I am doing wrong. I made a new php file named prologin.php where I have only this: `<?php var_dump($_POST['nam']); ?>` and it seems like there is nothing POSTED with POST. How can that be? You can see my FORM in the HTML. It does not look wrong... What is wrong?

Comment: do you have experience with jQuery Mobile and PHP? I believe this is my problem. If I remove the jQuery.mobile script line from the HTML, then the POST works fine. But I cannot do that since it would ruin my app... so what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Strip your php down until you find the offending code. I would replace instances of $_REQUEST for $_POST and echo them when the page is loaded to make sure that they're being passed OK. The fact that your query echos out with blank parameters makes me think that $_REQUEST is an issue..

```
<?php
 echo $_POST['nam'];
 echo $_POST['pas'];
```

at the beginning, and see what happens when the page is processed..

Comment: I removed all other code and I ended up with the problem: the jQuery.mobile script is doing this. If I remove from the HTML, the reference to jquery.mobile.js, then the post goes through. If I let it in my HTML, then the POST goes empty to the PHP. What can this mean, and how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I should have added this to the FORM:

```
data-ajax="false"
```

in order to prevent jQuery mobile from hijacking my submit behavior. 
After I added this to the form , POST is working properly.
Thank you for your time and ideas but they did not help me solve my problem. However you might find this info useful in the future.

Comment: Well my friend im glad you solved it but no where in your post we can see that your are using jQuery